# Python tryexcept for splitting with "-"

Tags: python, string, input, split, try-except

I'm working with a program where the user are supposed to type in a time in the format

```
Visiting between 10-17
```

I then split this string by split("-") and creates a list with the two strings i recieve, in this case "10" and "17".

Now I'm trying to fix so that the user can type in `ANYTHING` and the loop will still go on until the user types in a time in the right format.
For example the user `CANNOT` arrive at: `weiosrfiowe` or `1000-1000` etc.

This try-except works for everything `EXCEPT` for when I put a "-"  in either the start or the beginning of my input, like for "`-weihdriowe`" it crashes. This is probably because it can't find anything to split in to two objects.

So now i have something like:

```
while True:
    try:
    Time = Input(when you want to come)
    #the user puts in 10-17
    Timesplit = Time.split("-")
```

How can I arrange my code, or do it in a smarter way, so my program doesnt crash?
Thanks!!

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question should be "How can I validate the user input and loop around if it's invalid?" The answer _might_ involve exception handling but that's unlikely given how simple the problem is (simple string checks - sounds like a regex)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

found = False
while not found:
    time = raw_input("when you want to come")
    if re.match("^\d+-\d+$", time):
        found = True
```